# Objective test for self-awareness?

Tags: awareness

Are there any means by which an observed entity (e.g.: an AI) can be tested for self-awareness using/applying/affecting mainly its visual-oral-auditory-senses and observed responses of same? Failing that, are there any such tests for organic life-forms?

Answer (score 4):

To test self-awareness in **animals there is the [Mirror test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_test)**. It involves painting something on the animal's head/face without their knowledge and observing what they do when they notice the paint in their own reflection in a mirror.

Additionally, [robots have been tested for simple self-awareness by researchers at Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute](http://www.cnet.com/news/cute-robot-politely-shows-self-awareness/).

Comment: I know of the mirror-test - they also used it with babies (a vid on youtube about it), put a sticker on their foreheads IIRC. The robot-test concerns proprietary theory/algorithm so cannot really conclude anything, but seems suspiciously like just a well written expert-system.